# ExtJS how to change route from viewA to viewB with paramaters

Tags: extjs

ExtJS version:7.0
I have two views:  viewA and viewB
The viewA's route is #A and viewB's route is #B
Now I want to change route from viewA to viewB using jump(1234 is the id paramater)
So my question is how viewB get the id paramater and do something like search etc
Thanks

I've no idea how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the attached documentation,

https://docs.sencha.com/ext/7.0.0/guides/application_architecture/router.html

The Main view should contain the route config of the different page with id/name and the redirect function handler should be in the MainController.
Please refer the below Coworkee Application where Routes are handled by the App.view.viewport.ViewportController for unauthenticated pages (e.g. #login) and by the App.view.main.MainController once a user has been successfully authenticated (e.g. #home, #person/{uuid}, etc.).

https://examples.sencha.com/coworkee/#home

Live Example for Testing and a better idea

https://github.com/sencha-extjs-examples/Coworkee/tree/master/client